# Custom getChildHtml Block After Closing HTML Tag

Tags: layout, ce-1.8.1.0

This may be a stupid question. Is it possible to call a custom block *after* the closing HTML tag in my templates? Here's what I've got so far, but the block is not included/rendered and there's nothing in the error logs.

File: **app/design/frontend/default/theme/layout/local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        ...
        <reference name="custom_block">
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="page/html/custom_block.phtml" />
        </reference>
        ...
    </default>
</layout>
```

File: **app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/html/custom_block.phtml**

```
<!-- boo! -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

And lastly, I call the block in the layout file(s) like so:

File: **app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/1column.phtml**

```
    ...
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_block') ?>
```

Have I got the scope of `getChildHtml()` wrong? I have cleared the cache manually a hundred times and re-indexed the site as much. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: What's even your reason for trying to output a static block after `</html>`? That [wouldn't even make sense](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your layout xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="custom_block" as="custom_block" template="page/html/custom_block.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But please don't output anything after `</html>`. It's wrong.